# Get associative array of each row in CodeIgniter ActiveRecord result

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

In CodeIgniter there is a function `query->row_array` which will give you an associative array of your result, mapping column names to values. However this function only works if there is a single row as a result.

What I need is a function which will return an associative array for each row in the query result.

I am currently doing:

```
$arr = array ();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  array_push ($arr, array("col1" => $row->col1, "col2" => $row->col2, ...));
}
return $arr;
```

Not only is this annoying to read and write, but it also doesn't scale as I add more columns to this table. I have similar code in several places, and I wish I could replace it with something that is cleaner.

I was hoping for something like:

```
$arr = array ();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  array_push ($arr, $row->to_array());
}
return $arr;
```

Is there something like that? Or even better:

```
return $query->result_array ();
```

Comment: There IS `result_array()`. Read the documentation first, search on SO or google before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this method,

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('table_id' => $id));

        $queryArr = $query->result();        

        foreach ($queryArr[0] as $key=>$val)
        {
            $row[$key]=$val;
        }

print_r($row); //$row will give associative array
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `result_array()` see the original documentation
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Sample code.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){ echo $row['title'];   echo $row['name'];   echo $row['body'];}
```

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->row();

or

$query->row();

Comment: It would be better if you could explain your answer to the audience in detail. Thanks for your effort in answering.